# How to put variables from PowerShell into a remote MySQL

Tags: mysql, powershell

I try to put variables from my PowerShell script into a MySQL database. I have no idea how to do this. I tried to google, but I could only find examples where the .Net framework needs to be installed.

Is there perhaps other possibilities that work without installation of MySQL on the client?

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details. .Net is built-in in Windows, so it doesn't need to be installed. Are you using Linux?

Comment: I don't think this could be done without installing either the MySQL commandline client or a MySQL database driver on the client computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell isn't a massive monolithic all-encompassing language, that can do everything out-of-the-box.

It is lightweight and supports only (relatively) basic functionality by default, however it has [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules) to extend functionality and libraries to complete a wider range of tasks.

As Powershell is .NET based, it can use most .NET libraries.

---

MySQL connectivity is not native to PowerShell, and requires the use of the [Connector/NET](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) or [CLI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/command-line-options.html)

Here's a [blog post](https://michlstechblog.info/blog/powershell-some-examples-to-use-a-mysql-database/) with some example Powershell code using the connector.